# How would we create a warning message from a server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have an array of cake names, that a user can access when they visit localhost:8080/cake, however they can also visit the individual quotes when they search the index of the "cake" eg localhost:8080/quotes/2 (this will return the "cake" at index 2)

```
 server.get('/cake/:index', (req, res) => 
 res.send(quotes[req.params.index])),
```

However what I'm struggling to do is, when a user types an index out of range (Greater than 20) such as 21 or 22 the server should give back an error message.
I tried using .find method but that didn't work either

Answer (score 0):

You can check the length of the quotes and compare it with the index. If there are 10 quotes, the index should not exceed 9, assuming the index starts from 0.

```js
 if (req.params.index >= quotes.length) {
   // add your error here
   return res.status(500).send('error');
 }
 res.send(quotes[req.params.index]));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should retrieve the third parameter that Express.js provides in the callback, which is usually called `next`. This parameter contains a function that you should use in order to provide the result or an error. This ensures that all of the layers that are responsible of handling the request (route handlers, middlewares, etc...) are traversed before providing a response :

```
server.get('/quotes/:index', (req, res, next) =>
  quotes[req.params.index] !== undefined ?
  next(null, quotes[req.params.index]) :
  next(`Error: index ${req.params.index} out of limits`)
);
```

Express.js will take care of sending an HTTP 500 error in case you send one as the first parameter of the `next` function.